# How to add column that is a number that corresponds to the date

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a column and I have a data frame that looks like this

```
     Date New.Recap Site
1    3/21/2020         N  Jag
2    3/21/2020         N  Jag
3    3/22/2020         N  Jag
4    3/23/2020         N  Jag
5    3/23/2020         N  Jag
6    3/23/2020         R  Jag
7    3/23/2020         N  Jag
8    3/23/2020         N  Jag
9    3/23/2020         R  Jag
10   3/23/2020         N  Jag
11   3/23/2020         N  Jag
12   3/24/2020         N  Bla
13   3/24/2020         N  Bla
14   3/25/2020         N  Bla
15   3/25/2020         N  Bla
```

Depending on the date I would like to add another column on the end that is the number 1-6 depending on the date that will be called the primary. For example, the dates 3/21/2020-3/23/2020 would be a 1 and hopefully look like this

```
          Date  Primary New.Recap Site
    1    3/21/2020   1      N  Jag
    2    3/21/2020   1      N  Jag
    3    3/22/2020   1      N  Jag
    4    3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    5    3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    6    3/23/2020   1      R  Jag
    7    3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    8    3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    9    3/23/2020   1      R  Jag
    10   3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    11   3/23/2020   1      N  Jag
    12   3/24/2020   2      N  Bla
    13   3/24/2020   2      N  Bla
    14   3/25/2020   2      N  Bla
    15   3/25/2020   2      N  Bla
```

Basically, I have a bunch of dates that fall into the category of being 1-6 depending on the date. The dates are always in groups of three consecutive days in a row. For the graphing, I need to use the Primary 1-6 numbers and not the dates. I have been trying to do this with the mutate function but I am not sure how to use it with dates.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a custom dates to recode, use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Primary = case_when(Date %in% 
            c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020")~ 1,
       TRUE ~ 2), .after = 'Date')
```

-output

```
#        Date Primary New.Recap Site
#1  3/21/2020       1         N  Jag
#2  3/21/2020       1         N  Jag
#3  3/22/2020       1         N  Jag
#4  3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#5  3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#6  3/23/2020       1         R  Jag
#7  3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#8  3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#9  3/23/2020       1         R  Jag
#10 3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#11 3/23/2020       1         N  Jag
#12 3/24/2020       2         N  Bla
#13 3/24/2020       2         N  Bla
#14 3/25/2020       2         N  Bla
#15 3/25/2020       2         N  Bla
```

---

Or another option is a key value dataset with 'Date' and corresponding 'Primary' values

```
keyval <- data.frame(Date = c("3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", "3/23/2020", 
 "3/24/2020"), Primary = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
```

and then do a join with the dataset

```
left_join(df1, keyval)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("3/21/2020", "3/21/2020", "3/22/2020", 
"3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", 
"3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/23/2020", "3/24/2020", "3/24/2020", 
"3/25/2020", "3/25/2020"), New.Recap = c("N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "R", "N", "N", "R", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), Site = c("Jag", 
"Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", 
"Jag", "Bla", "Bla", "Bla", "Bla")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for `cut`. Your date doesn't seem in proper format though, so first we need

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

then

```
dat <- transform(dat, 
                 Primary=cut(Date, c(min(Date), as.Date("2020-03-24"), max(Date)),
                             include.lowest=T, labels=1:2))
dat
#          Date New.Recap Site Primary
# 1  2020-03-21         N  Jag       1
# 2  2020-03-21         N  Jag       1
# 3  2020-03-22         N  Jag       1
# 4  2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 5  2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 6  2020-03-23         R  Jag       1
# 7  2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 8  2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 9  2020-03-23         R  Jag       1
# 10 2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 11 2020-03-23         N  Jag       1
# 12 2020-03-24         N  Bla       2
# 13 2020-03-24         N  Bla       2
# 14 2020-03-25         N  Bla       2
# 15 2020-03-25         N  Bla       2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18342, 18342, 18343, 18344, 
18344, 18344, 18344, 18344, 18344, 18344, 18344, 18345, 18345, 
18346, 18346), class = "Date"), New.Recap = c("N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "R", "N", "N", "R", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), 
    Site = c("Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", 
    "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Jag", "Bla", "Bla", "Bla", "Bla")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"), class = "data.frame")
```